Macro for converting Latex embedding code to Word equation editor
Latex plugins for Google Docs often have you provide Latex code between $$, for instance $$a+b$$.
Word now natively supports Latex code within it's equation editor, which is plus. However, if you've prepared your document in elsewhere you need to tell Word that text between the $$ is Latex code for the equation editor. And deleting the $$ would be great to boot.
What's the best way to write a Macro to do this?
For example consider the text:
When evaluating a product, there are two types of correct judgments: approving a product that meets standards (approve $$A$$, quality meets standards $$S$$) results in a payoff of $$v_h$$, while rejecting a product that does not meet standards (reject $$\lnot A$$, quality does not meet standards $$\lnot S$$) yields a payoff of $$v_c$$. Errors occur when a product is wrongly approved (approve $$A$$, quality does not meet standards $$\lnot S$$), leading to a loss of $$v_f$$, or when a product that meets standards is wrongly rejected (reject $$\lnot A$$, quality meets standards $$S$$), resulting in a loss of $$v_m$$. It is better to approve a product that meets standards than to miss it ($$v_h > v_m$$), but it is also better to reject a substandard product than to approve it unnecessarily ($$v_c > v_f$$). The likelihood that a product meets the required standards is given by the probability $$p = \mathrm{P}(S)$$.
I tried this code, but it doesn't work very well, and i'm extremely confused about how the scripting language works.
Sub ConvertToEquations()

    Dim doc As Document
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim startPos As Long
    Dim endPos As Long
    Dim found As Boolean
    
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    Set rng = doc.Content
    
    ' Move to the beginning of the document
    rng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
    
    ' Search for $$
    Do While rng.Find.Execute(FindText:="$$", MatchWildcards:=False)
        ' Mark the position of the first $$
        startPos = rng.Start + 2
        
        ' Move the range to the position after the first $$
        rng.Start = startPos
        
        ' Search for the closing $$
        found = rng.Find.Execute(FindText:="$$", MatchWildcards:=False)
        
        If found Then
            endPos = rng.Start
            
            ' Set the range for the text between $$
            Set rng = doc.Range(startPos, endPos)
            
            ' Convert the text to an equation
            rng.OMaths.Add rng
            rng.OMaths.BuildUp
            
            ' Collapse the range to the end of the current range
            rng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
            
            ' Move the range two characters forward
            rng.MoveEnd Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=2
            rng.MoveStart Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=2
        Else
            ' If no closing $$ is found, exit the loop
            Exit Do
        End If
        
    Loop

End Sub



"it doesn't work very well" can you be a bit more specific? Does it work but take a very long time to execute? Does it only achieve the desired result once in awhile?

Yes thank you. It only partially achieves the desired result, it'll get to a certain equation then a runtime error will occur.

As far as I can tell, the main problem is that when you execute
rng.OMaths.Buildup

Word collapses rng to its beginning, which means the attempt to move beyond the closing "$$" fails.
Here, I could fix by adding the following lines after the Buildup:
Set rng = rng.OMaths(1).Range
rng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd

but you might prefer to achieve that another way.
Another possible problem is that unless you select LaTeX input mode before you start, Word probably isn't going to interpret the equation text as LaTeX. You may be able to fix that using the followin at the beginning of your code:
Application.Dialogs(2844).Execute ' The only way I know to invoke the Word EquationModeLatex command from VBA.
DoEvents ' just in case.

